# How to do a fit with gnuplot using data with error in x and y?

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting

How to do a fit with data like x y deltax delta y? I have to do a linear fit weighted to the error in both axis what is the exact syntax?

Fit `f (x)  "file.txt" u1:2:3:4` via `a`, `b` with `xyerrorbars`.

```
f (x) =a*x + b
```

Result: singular matrix in invert_RtR

Comment: The `xyerrorbar` style is for plotting. You cannot give `with` styles for fitting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fit with x and y errors you need gnuplot 5. Then use the syntax

```
f(x) = a*x + b
fit f(x) "file.txt" using 1:2:3:4 xyerrors via a,b
```

See the last example on http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/fit.html for a full demo.

Comment: I have gnuplot 5 i'll try

Answer (score -2):

Since there is no code that you tried beforehand so we can edit it, I'm providing a very generic solution here.

For linear fit, use `using (1)` in your fit command for equal weights. For examples of fit command syntax, [see this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14734459/4780877). Of course, [the manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf) has complete details of `fit` and `using`.